# How to extract the last records based on entrydate sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have many duplicate job id but entry date is can not be duplicate. i need to fetch always unique job id based on last entry date. i have solved it with the below query but like to know is there any better way to form the same sql when data would be huge for best performance. please guide me thanks.

```
SELECT  A.JID,A.EntryDate,RefundDate,Comments,Refund, ActionBy 
FROM    (
            (
            select  JID, Max(EntryDate) AS EntryDate 
            from    refundrequested 
            GROUP BY JID
            ) A 
            Inner JOIN 
            (
                    SELECT  JID,ENTRYDATE,refundDate,Comments,refund,ActionBy 
                    from    refundrequested
            ) B 
            ON A.JID=B.JID AND A.EntryDate = B.EntryDate
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `row_number()` function is usually a bit faster:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by jid 
                                   order by EntryDate desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    refundrequested
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT t1.JID,
       t1.EntryDate,
       t1.RefundDate,
       t1.Comments,
       t1.Refund, 
       t1.ActionBy
FROM refundrequested t1
LEFT JOIN refundrequested t2
  ON t2.JID = t1.JID
  AND t2.EntryDate > t1.EntryDate
WHERE t2.JID is null
```

Comment: what would be difference in performance if u use LEFT JOIN isntead of inner join? please explain. thanks

Comment: with inner join you don't get null in second table... in this query I compare if in t2 table are rows with bigger entrydate than in first table, so basically I'm searching for biggest entrydate and then second table would not have records it means that in first table there are biggest entrydate...